# select2 (v4.0.2) dynamically change options and selections

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using selec2 plugin of version v4.0.2.
I need to dynamically change (append and remove) options and selections.
My usage of select2 is as a **multi selected items visualizer**, so consider situation :

1. click on button
2. get needed data from some element (for example another select)
3. set this data as selected in select2
4. repeat from step 1. and append selected data

I also need to hold selected data localy (in an array for example) - before form submit i will post this data to my framework code and proccess them. 
So if user kills an item with "x", i need to remove this item from select2 selection (this is done as default), but also update my local selection storage (array).

I need to use select2 as a **visualizer and holder of selected data only**, dropdown options should be identic with selected options and dynamically changed.

Can u please help me with a snippet of code, or suggestion of another plugin for my purposes ?
Thank you